# Trouble making Java Roulette game

Tags: java

I'm working on a roulette game and I'm having an error with my makeDecision method in my Roulette class. The reason is because I am having trouble with the updatePot method in my Player class and am not sure what to do in it. I am using 4 classes, here is my code for each:

```
public class Assign3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Roulette roulette = new Roulette();
        roulette.run();
    }

}
```

and

```
public class Roulette {

    private String decision;

    Player player = new Player();
    Wheel wheel = new Wheel();

    private void makeDecision(){
        String bet = player.getBet();
        try {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(bet);
            if (value == wheel.getValue()){
                decision = " you win 40 times your bet";
                player.updatePot(40);
            } else {
                decision = "you lose the game";
                player.updatePot(0);
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e){
            if (bet.equals("odd")){
                if (wheel.getValue() %2 == 0){
                    decision = "you lose the game";
                    player.updatePot(0);
                } else {
                    decision = "you win double your bet";
                    player.updatePot(2);
                }
            } else if (bet.equals("equals")){
                if (wheel.getValue() %2 == 0){
                    decision = "you win double your bet";
                    player.updatePot(2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void displayDecision(){

    }

    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Welcome to Cache Creek style Roulette..bet an amount and type\n"
                            + " if you select the correct colour, you win double your bet\n"
                            + " if you select the correct odd/even, you win double your bet\n"
                            + " if you select the right number, you win 40 times your bet\n"
                            + " otherwise you lose your bet\n"
                            + " If you lose all your money, the game is over");

        do {
            player.setBetAmount();
            player.setBet();
            wheel.spin();
            wheel.display();
            makeDecision();
            displayDecision();
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

and

```
package Assignment3;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Player {

    private int pot = 0;
    private int amount = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void setBetAmount() {
        System.out.print("\nHow much do you want to bet? ");
        amount = input.nextInt();
        int pot =100;
        if (amount > pot || amount < 1){
            System.out.print("Invalid bet amount..How much do you want to bet? ");
            amount = input.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public void setBet() {
        System.out.print("What is your bet? (odd/even/red/black/exact number)");

    }

    public String getBet() {
        return null;
    }

    public void updatePot(int i) {

    }

}
```

and

```
package Assignment3;

import java.util.Random;

public class Wheel {
    private int value;

    private String colour;
    Random random;

    public Wheel(){
        value = 0;
        colour = null;
        random = new Random();
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getColour(){
        return colour;
    }

    public void spin(){
        value = random.nextInt(39)+1;
        colour = (random.nextInt(1)==0)?"red":"black";
    }

    public void display(){
        System.out.print(value+" "+colour);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you describe that the `updatePot` is supposed to do?

Comment: If the player makes a correct bet, updatePot should add how much they win to their existing pot.

Comment: Okay thanks, I am also having problems setting a bet. The bet can be an integer or String, how would I set up the input?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The player is asked to bet the colour, number or odd/even of a randomly generated card. If they get the correct colour or odd/even, they gain twice their bet, if they get the correct number, gain forty times their bet. I am not sure how to set up the input of their bet because they can bet an int or String.

Comment: If they enter a number, are you going to treat it any differently than if they enter a string?  I don't think you are, so just make the method only accept a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the input for your program has to be a String because your Player can input both text or a specific number. You then have to check this String for the occurence of either (odd/even/red/black) or a valid number. If neither is true then the input is invalid.

When looking at your code you need to think about how you want your updatePot method to work.

- Should it set the pot to the given value (that's what the method name would suggest to me)
- Should it add the given value to the pot or
- Should it multiply the current pot value by the given value

When you have decided how it should work you have to update your Roulette.makeDecision() method.
Good luck with your assignment!
Markus

Answer (score 0):

Just change the datatype of bet from String to int and then add your updatePot methode. You will also need to adjust your NumberFormatException.